# Wrap lines without breaking words

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap test in a paragraph without breaking the words it it. Currently words are breaked while wrapping.

e.g.

`"Hello World Programmers"` becomes

```
"Hello World Progr
ammers"
```

I want it to behave like

```
"Hello World
Programmers"
```

I've used `word-break:keep-all` property but it doesn't solve my problem. What I am doing wrong. Please tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `word-break` (or set it to `normal`) and you should be fine.

Comment: this does the work for me. Thanks. Also I wasn't applying style directly to <P>.

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
word-wrap:normal
```

More info on [w3scools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3%5fpr%5fword-wrap.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just set it like `word-break:normal` 
Here the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6JZp/3/)